# How to save datetime column value in SQLServer 2014 from java

Tags: java, datetime

I tried using java.util.Date and java.sql.Date but in both the cases time part is not getting saved.

if date is 2015-11-16 17:53:49.6

it is saving it as 2015-11-16 00:00:00.000 in SQL Server.

Comment: Do you mind using varchar instead of date?

Comment: What technology / library do you use for database connection?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) of java.sql.Date as it represents only date not the time(*so the time value will be 00:00:00.000 which you are getting*). So you have to add the time explicitly in your code or better use [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values
>   wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting
>   the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the
>   particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

Answer (score 0):

Does using `java.sql.Timestamp` work ?

Check the data type of the SQL Server column too.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378878(v=sql.110).aspx - This might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL GETDATE() function to get the current data and time.You can also fix it as default value while defining the table.
Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
OrderId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ProductName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

Moreover for insert statement you can use the query like this

```
INSERT INTO Orders (ColumnName) VALUES (GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive the same with the conversion like this

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Date;

class A3{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        String dateWithSeconds = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println(dateWithSeconds);
    }
}
```